# Reading data from a file that contains special characters using `io:fileReadString`

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I'm reading a file with the extension [`.p12`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12), which contains special characters. I want to verify that [`io:fileReadString`](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/io/1.6.0#fileReadString) accurately returns the data from the file. That is,

```
string inputData = check io:fileReadString(inputFile);
check io:fileWriteString(outputFile, inputData);
string outputData = check io:fileReadString(outputFile);
test:assertEquals(inputData, outputData);
```

Answer (score 0):

`io:fileReadString` assumes you are reading a text file encoded with `UTF-8` encoding. Furthermore, it strips away the carriage return (`\n` or `\r`) from the end of the file, which means if you read a file using `io:fileReadString` and write it back even if it is valid UTF-8 it could still be different since it stripped away the carriage return at the end of the file. Also if the file in question has byte sequences that are not valid `UTF-8` byte sequences it may write completely different values to the file. To better illustrate the point consider the example,

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() returns error? {
    byte[] seq = [97, 161, 10, 98, 10]; // <invalid>, \n, b, \n
    string fileName = "test.b";
    check io:fileWriteBytes(fileName, seq);
    byte[] data = check io:fileReadBytes(fileName);
    io:println(data); // [97, 161, 10, 98, 10]
    string str = check io:fileReadString(fileName);
    io:println(str); // a<invalidchar>\nb (note no \n at the end)
    check io:fileWriteString(fileName, str);
    data = check io:fileReadBytes(fileName); // [97, 239, 191, 189, 10, 98]
    io:println(data); // [97, 10, 98]
}
```

Therefore if you are reading a file that is not valid UTF-8 or need to rewrite the exact content back you must use the [`io:fileReadBytes`](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/io/1.6.0#fileReadBytes) read the file and write it back using [`io:fileWriteBytes`](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/io/1.6.0#fileWriteBytes)